# Make jsf selectOneMenu open upwards

Tags: jsf

I have a selectOneMenu at the bottom of my page and by default when I click it the menu drops below the bottom of the page.  Is there a way to get it to render backwards (ie upwards)?

Comment: This would be true of any [HTML select control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6). You may get more responses by restating the problem and retagging as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self-respected browser will already do it automatically if there's no viewport room below the dropdown.

If you want to *always* drop it up, even though there's enough room in the viewport to drop it down, then your only solution is to turn it into a `<ul><li>` and throw in a bunch of CSS/JS code to make it look like a <strike>dropdown</strike> dropup. I Googled using keyword "dropup" and found those examples:

- http://aplus.rs/adxmenu/examples/hbt/
- http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/dropup.htm

---

**Update** as per the comments: oh boy, why didn't you mention from the beginning on that you were using PrimeFaces' `<p:selectOneMenu>`? Since you didn't mention anything about 3rd party component libraries I assumed it to be the standard JSF `<h:selectOneMenu>`. The PrimeFaces one generates an `<ul><li>` to achieve the sexy look'n'feel!

I'm not going to dig in the whole bunch of PrimeFaces CSS to give you a fine-grained answer, but to start off, you need to set the following style in your custom CSS:

```css
.ui-selectonemenu-panel {
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

This will cause the menu to go up instead of down. There are some stylistic misbehaviours (it hides the current selection), but that's up to you (just finetune the `bottom` to `30px` or something). You can otherwise also just use a `<h:selectOneMenu>` and delegate the job to the browser.

Comment: Both Firefox 6 and IE9 are rendering the menu downwards.  I may have to hand code it but I figured there had to be some way to make standard JSF make the menu go up instead of down.

Comment: FF6 and IE9 (and GC13 and Safari5) don't do that here (only when the browser window is that small resized that there's enough viewport room below). Might be OS specific. What are you using? Win7 Pro x64 here. Further, may I please remind you that JSF is "just" a HTML code generator? Your problem is to be solved in HTML area, not in JSF area, as that's all what the browsers retrieve. If something's not possible in HTML, then JSF simply can't do any much for you.

Comment: I am running on Win7 Home Prem x64 on this box.  I understand that JSF essentially gets compiled down to lower HTML code (ie C++ vs assembly where JSF is C++).

I am looking at the links you posted to try to figure out what they are doing to make the menu render backwards.

Comment: JSF is not compiled to HTML :) Those examples just use `<ul><li>` enriched with a bunch of CSS/JS to make it look like a dropdown/up. In JSF side, you could put a `<h:commandLink>` in each `<li>`, if necessary along with `<f:ajax>`.

Comment: How about "results in" :)

True, could use commandlink to kick off methods in my bean.

Comment: The "dropup" menu is actually a dropdown with the menu items given a negative starting point (top: -300px) so it isnt actually being rendered upwards.  I need to keep looking.

Comment: Ah that might explain it. I used `bottom: 0` to test it and it works fine. Can't you just position it relative from the bottom on?

Comment: I have tried it positioned relative, fixed and absolute to the bottom and it still shows the menu going down below the screen.

Comment: I mean, `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`. The word "relative" in my previous answer was admittedly ambiguous.

Comment: <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:10px">
   <p:selectOneMenu value="0" style="width:100px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Action" itemValue="0"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Kill Session" itemValue="1"/>
   </p:selectOneMenu>
  </div>

With the above code it still shows the menu extending off the bottom.

Comment: You're using PrimeFaces without mentioning anything about it... See answer update.

Comment: Ahh crap, my original typing had p:selectOneMenu so I must have gone back and cleaned up my original post which had the unfortunately side effect of removing the "PrimeFaces" annotation.  I will update the css, thanks.

Comment: Im not sure how to answer this question since the css didnt work for me using PrimeFaces-3.0.M3 but I was able to do something similar using a dynamically positioned menu.

Comment: It works for me. Apparently you've still put it in some other absolutely positioned div or something.